# ESPAsyncWebServer request->send_P problem

Tags: esp32

I am doing a simple example using ESPAsyncWebServer on ESP32. In this context I wrote a html file (there are a slider and a button) and tested it on a browser until the content look well. Then I integrate it in the C++ source code for ESP32. It works and look as expected until I don't add a callback to read the value of the slider.
This is the complete source code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char ssid[]    = "Vodafone-A40881218";
const char pswd[]    = "rJbFMktHCcqN67Ye";

const int output = 2;

String sliderValue = "0";

// setting PWM properties
const int freq = 5000;
const int ledChannel = 0;
const int resolution = 8;

const char* PARAM_INPUT = "value";

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

#if 0
const char old_index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>ESP Web Server</title>
  <style>
    html {font-family: Arial; display: inline-block; text-align: center;}
    h2 {font-size: 2.3rem;}
    p {font-size: 1.9rem;}
    body {max-width: 400px; margin:0px auto; padding-bottom: 25px;}
    .slider { -webkit-appearance: none; margin: 14px; width: 360px; height: 25px; background: #FFD65C; outline: none; -webkit-transition: .2s; transition: opacity .2s;}
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none; width: 35px; height: 35px; background: #003249; cursor: pointer;}
    .slider::-moz-range-thumb { width: 35px; height: 35px; background: #003249; cursor: pointer; } 

    button { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:20%;color:white;font-size:130%; }
      .buttons { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:15%;color:white;font-size:80%; }
      .buttonsm { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:9%; color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttonm { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:15%;color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttonw { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:40%;color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttong { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:40%;color:white;font-size:130%; }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>ESP Web Server</h2>
  <p><span id="textSliderValue">%SLIDERVALUE%</span></p>
  <p><input type="range" onchange="updateSliderPWM(this)" id="pwmSlider" min="0" max="21" value="%SLIDERVALUE%" step="1" class="slider"></p>
  <a href='/setup'><button class='button'>SETUP</button></a>
<script>
function updateSliderPWM(element) {
  var sliderValue = document.getElementById("pwmSlider").value;
  document.getElementById("textSliderValue").innerHTML = sliderValue;
  console.log(sliderValue);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/slider?value="+sliderValue, true);
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
)rawliteral";
#endif

const char index_html[] = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ESP Web Server</title>
    <style>
      html {font-family: Arial; display: inline-block; text-align: center;}
      h2 {font-size: 2.3rem;}
      p {font-size: 1.9rem;}
      body {max-width: 400px; margin:0px auto; padding-bottom: 25px;}
      .slider { width: 360px; }  
      .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { width: 50px; height: 50px; }
      .slider::-moz-range-thumb { width: 50px; height: 50px; } 
      button { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:40%;color:white;font-size:130%; }
      .buttons { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:15%;color:white;font-size:80%; }
      .buttonx { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:9%; color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttonm { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:15%;color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttonw { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:40%;color:white;font-size:70%; }
      .buttong { border-radius:0.5em;background:#C20000;padding:0.3em 0.3em;width:40%;color:white;font-size:130%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>ESP Web Server</h2>
    <p><span id="textSliderValue">%SLIDERVALUE%</span></p>
    <p><input type="range" onchange="updateSliderPWM(this)" id="pwmSlider" min="0" max="21" value="%SLIDERVALUE%" step="1" class="slider"></p>
    <a href='/setup'><button class='button'>SETUP</button></a>
    <script>
      function updateSliderPWM(element) {
        var sliderValue = document.getElementById("pwmSlider").value;
        document.getElementById("textSliderValue").innerHTML = sliderValue;
        console.log(sliderValue);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "/slider?value="+sliderValue, true);
        xhr.send();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
)rawliteral";
// Replaces placeholder with button section in your web page

String processor(const String& var)
{
  //Serial.println(var);
  if (var == "SLIDERVALUE"){
    return sliderValue;
  }
  return String();
}

#include <Preferences.h>
Preferences Pref;
int32_t g_iVolume = 0;

void setup()
{
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Pref.begin("datasetup", false);
  g_iVolume = Pref.getInt("volume", 5);
  Serial.print("volume="); Serial.println(g_iVolume);
  sliderValue = String(g_iVolume);
  Pref.end();

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pswd);
  Serial.println("Connecting ...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect: scan for Wi-Fi networks, and connect to the strongest of the networks above
    delay(250); 
    Serial.print('.');
  }

  // Print ESP Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/slider?value=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/slider", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String inputMessage;
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/slider?value=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT)->value();
      sliderValue = inputMessage;
      int ival = sliderValue.toInt();
      Serial.print("ival="); Serial.println(ival);
      Pref.begin("datasetup", false);
      size_t st = Pref.putInt("volume", ival);
      Pref.end();
      Serial.print("st="); Serial.println(st);

      Pref.begin("datasetup", false);
      int vol = Pref.getInt("volume", -1);
      Serial.print("volume="); Serial.println(vol);
      Pref.end();
    }
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
    }
    Serial.println(inputMessage);
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "OK");
  });
  
  // Start server
  server.begin();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------


void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the 1st image is with nullptr instead of processor and the 2nd with processor callback.

[image: then this is the image with nullptr instead of processor:]

[image: and then this is the image with processor callback]

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. What is the question? It sounds like you're saying the code doesn't do what you want when you don't add the callback but does when you do add it. Could you please clarify what you're asking about? Please be clear about what it's supposed to do and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: I am asking if someone had the same problem and eventually found a solution or not.

Comment: What problem?  The problem isn’t clear from your question.

Comment: It is simple to understand, in:     request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);    if I put nullptr the output looks as the 1st image, instead if I leave processor it looks as the 2nd image. processor is a function to retrieve the value for the slider, for this reason in the 1st image you see a place holder (%SLIDERVALUE%) instead of 4. So, seems to me that if I call processot the output is corrupted.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. If you don't call the processor, the placeholder can't be replaced by the value. Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: If your concern is about the size of the "setup" button it would be helpful if you just said that.

Comment: Well.... I attached 2 images I do not think more is needed to understand what the problem is, the 2 buttons are very different not only the size.

Comment: Well.... the problem is not that, is the different style of the button and if I add more controls also those look different then set by style parameters. Seems that only the slider looks always as designed.

Comment: You are asking strangers for help. Make it easy for them by actually asking the question you’re asking. Don’t expect them to have to figure out your question I order to then help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The author of ESPAsyncWebServer decided to use the % character as the delimiter for placeholders for the template processor. Unfortunately, the % is quite common in CSS and JavaScript so, writing CSS and JavaScript in HTML file(s) or Strings does not work as expected because the wrong interpretation of % as delimiters of chuncks of text that are not placeholders but CSS or JavaScript code. At the moment there is not a workaround, just do not use % in CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing the delimiter character (%) to a ($).
To do this you have to modify the definition of "TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER" which is in the file "ESPAsyncWebServer\src\WebResponseImpl.h"

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER
#define TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER '$' <<<<
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of "ESPAsyncWebServer" you are using, but I am using the one from the "ESPAsyncWebServer-esphome (version:3.0.0)" library.

In this, if the variable "TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER" is not created, it is created with the value '$' by default, you can change it to the value you want.
In the code that you show, it says that if that variable is defined. It is undefined and defined again with the new value, but if it still does not exist, that piece of code does nothing. You should change it to this:

```
#ifdef  TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER       //if the macro TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER is defined
   #undef  TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER    //un-define it
#endif
#define TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER '$'   // define it with the new value
```

Answer (score 0):

Great find that TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER '%' is the problem.
Found this with text such as "width: 100%;"

Instead of editing WebResponseImpl.h

in platformio.ini in build_flags section add

```
-D TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER=36 ; '$'
```

Note that TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER='$' wont work

Answer (score -1):

indeed.
i checked for in my main programm to do this:

```
#ifdef  TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER    //if the macro TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER is defined

#undef  TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER    //un-define it

#define TEMPLATE_PLACEHOLDER '$'//redefine it with the new value

#endif
```

but this doesn't work...
Perhaps someone guru knows how to prioritize the defines in such a way that a separate #define overrules the one in WebResponseImpl.h